# Jade dynamic data

Tags: node.js, pug, string-interpolation

Using node.js I am passing some variables to jade view:

```
res.render('index', {
        locals: { 
                      name: user.name, 
                      hashpassword: JSON.stringify(user.hashPass), 
                      languages: JSON.stringify(langs)}
                });
```

In jade file I have:

```
body
    #heading
      h1 nodechat
      label !{locals.languages} // working - printing whole json string
    #content
      - var laangs = !{locals.languages} //not working here!
                   //SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

      - each item in laangs
        label= item.EnglishName
```

The problem is that I cannot pass locals.languages to a variable in jade file. If I assign it to  a single html element (like label), it's working, but when I try with ***var =*** that doesn't work.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my change below...

```
body
    #heading
      h1 nodechat
      label !{locals.languages} // working - printing whole json string
    #content
      //- Do it like this...You're already in JavaScript land after the -
      - var laangs = locals.languages
      - each item in laangs
        label= item.EnglishName
```

Change **!{locals.languages}** into **locals.languages**

Comment: That's it! And the worst thing is, I had tried that before asking the question, but I forgot to re-run the code, so the changes were not seen in the browser...
Thanks!

Comment: @misaizdaleka, to see changes immediately in the browser, check out node-supervisor and LiveReload.